# Multiple authenciation methods in one ASP.NET Core 2.2 controller

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application which is running on CentOS, but still requires an authorisation based on Active Directory properties. I therefore wrote a custom `AuthenticationHandler` using Novell's LDAP library, which will determine the required claims. This works all fine, but it is slow.

I therefore added JWT as a second authentication method. This works, too, on its own. The configuration in Startup.cs looks like:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(cfg => {
    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    cfg.SaveToken = true;

    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
        // Omitted for brevity
    };
})
.AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, MyAuthenticationHandler>(Constants.MyAuthenticationScheme, null);

services.AddAuthorization(o => {
    o.AddPolicy(Constants.AuthorisationPolicy, p => p.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, "group"));
});
```

The problem, which took me quite some time to identify, arises in the following situation: First, I want to use the bearer token only for read requests, not for changes. Second, the XSRF token requires operations with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute to use the authentication method if the page, so I must use my own method here. Therefore, I came up with the following construct:

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = Constants.AuthorisationPolicy)]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/structure")]
[ApiController]
public sealed class DirectoryStructureController : ControllerBase {
    //...

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("create")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = Constants.MyAuthenticationScheme,
        Policy = Constants.AuthorisationPolicy)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult<Result> Create([FromForm] string folder) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This construct works – it uses my custom authentication for `Create` and JWT for the other operations (because it is the default), *but only* if `Create` is the first operation that is called on the controller. If I invoke any other operation (using JWT) before, `Create` fails with a 401 with a `www-authenticate: Bearer` header. Using JWT once somehow "burns" the controller so it cannot use my custom handler any more.

Is there any way to fix this? I guess I could add another controller only for creates and updates, but I am reluctant to rip the application logic apart. So is there a per-method fix?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

**Edit:** The custom authentication handler is quite complex, but the following minimal version reproduces the behaviour (it authenticates everyone and issues the required group claim):

```cs
public sealed class MyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> {

    public MyAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
         : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() {
        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "user"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, "group")
        };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, this.Scheme.Name);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, this.Scheme.Name);
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
```

The corresponding controller issuing the JWT bearer token would be:

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = Constants.MyAuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TokenController : ControllerBase {

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "user"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, "group")
        };

        var creds = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("key")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var expires = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken("issuer", "audience", claims,
            expires: expires,
            signingCredentials: creds);

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var retval = handler.WriteToken(token);

        return this.Ok(new {
            Token = token,
            LifeTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
        });
    }
}
```

In JavaScript, one would retrieve a token like

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/token'
}).done(function (data, statusText, xhdr) {
    // Save the token
}.bind(this)).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    // Handle error
}.bind(this));
```

and use it like

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/structure/somemethod'
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    }
}).done(function (data, statusText, xhdr) {
    // Use the result of somemethod
}.bind(this)).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    // Handle error
}.bind(this));
```

After this call, any subsequent call would fail as described above:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/structure/create',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: '=' + folder,
    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': xsrftok // From @Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(this.HttpContext).RequestToken
    }
}).done(function (data, statusText, xhdr) {
    // Show success message
}.bind(this)).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    // Handle error
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: How did you implement `MyAuthenticationHandler`? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I cannot post all the stuff, because it is distributed over several classes, but I have added an authenticator and a controller that produce the same behaviour. As you see, both methods issue the same claims, but I need to use `MyAuthenticationHandler` because of `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`